# Validating a user's String type 'menu choice'

Tags: java, eclipse, string, while-loop, boolean

An assignment we were given recently had us building a basic, console-based, 'Tax Calculator', as it is something that got us to implement the things we'd learnt so far - variables, constants, loops etc.

One part of it had us present the user with a menu, where they would enter a letter - be it a,b,c,d or x - depending on what they wanted to do next.

That was no drama, as our assignment didn't ask for us to account for what happened if a user entered a choice not on the menu.

Now, for my own personal interest, I went back to it today, wanting to put some validation in there.

I defined the 'menuChoiceRule':
(`menuChoice` being a String)

```
    boolean menuChoiceRule = (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
            || (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
            || (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
            || (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) 
            || (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("X"));
```

And here is what should happen for as long as the rule is being broken: (The program should keep asking until it gets something that is in keeping with the rule, and then stop asking)

```
    while (menuChoiceRule == false) {
        System.out.print(menuChoiceString);
        System.out.print("Enter Your Selection");
        menuChoice = SCANNER.nextLine();
    }
```

And what happens if the user is doing the right thing:

```
    // As long as the user input is 'A','B','C' or 'D', they'll be able to
    // keep doing stuff.
    while (menuChoiceRule == true) {
        *All the various menu options go here*
    }
```

At the moment the `while(menuChoiceRule == true)` block (is that the right term?) works fine but `while(menuChoiceRule == false)` does not; Once the user inputs something that is in violation of the `menuChoiceRule`, the loop repeats endlessly no matter what is input (inputted?)

If someone could provide some insight as to why I'm having trouble here, it'd be much appreciated.

Regards,
AUS_Doug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the boolean test is not being changed within the loop, place the code again at the bottom of the while loop.

Also, boolean tests do not need the ==, `while(menuChoiceRule){ ...` is the preferred coding style.

I would also consider creating a method to test for your rule:

```
private boolean testChoice(String menuChoice) {
        return ((menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
             || (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
             || (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
             || (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) 
             || (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("X")));
}
```

This would give rise to the code:

```
boolean validChoice = false;

while (!validChoice) {
    System.out.print(menuChoiceString);
    System.out.print("Enter Your Selection");
    menuChoice = SCANNER.nextLine();
    validChoice = testChoice(menuChoice);
}
```

Comment: There we go, creating that method makes things much simpler, cheers for that.